# Why use an async function with await instead of just a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Forgive me but I am trying to learn Javascript with Node and cannot get my head around why this piece of code needs an `async function`. I thought asynchronous functions were meant to be 'triggered' and then forgotten about to do something in the background and return a result at a later time.

Therefore, in the following code (Express router) what is the purpose of using async/await in the callback function and not just having it as a normal function (removing the `async` and `await` code)?

```
router.get('/homepage', async function (req, res)  {  // why async here?
    let HomepageFeed;
    try {
        HomepageFeed = await api.getHomepageFeed();   // if you're await-ing here?
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 404) {
            return res.status(404).send('404 | Page Not Found');
        }
        return res.status(500).send('500 | Internal Server Error');
    }
    res.json(HomepageFeed);
});
```

Comment: For the comments: _"The `await` operator is used to wait for a Promise. **It can only be used inside an `async` function**."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await))

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: `async` / `await` is just syntactic sugar for a `Promise`. Anything after the `await` would be in the `.then()` handler of the `Promise`. Without the`try`/`catch` it would be like `api.getHomepageFeed().then(feed => res.json(feed))`

Comment: So if I did `router.get('/homepage', function (req, res) { let HomepageFeed = api.getHomepageFeed() res.json(HomepageFeed) });` it might return nothing because the `api.HomepageFeed()` was still fetching data by the time `res.json(HomepageFeed)` is sent back? Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: @volumeone Yes. Apparently your `api.HomepageFeed()` function returns a promise, and you want to wait for that and send its result as the response.

Comment: @Bergi my `api.HomepageFeed()` just does this: `function HomepageFeed() {
 return // database recordset here
}`

Comment: @volumeone Surely it fetches the database recordset asynchronously, and returns a promise for it?